# Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
sympol = [input()]
abc = YahooFinancials(sympol)
l=abc.get_financial_stmts('annual', 'cash')
df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(key) for key in l['cashflowStatementHistory']['FB']],axis=1,sort=True).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Time'})
```

Thank you it works but only with specific sympol. How to make it customised so that I can enter any symbol instead. What to write instead of 'FB'. I tried `[[sympol]] but it gives my an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

      7 l=abc.get_financial_stmts('annual', 'cash')
----> 8 df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(key) for key in l['cashflowStatementHistory'][[sympol]]],axis=1,sort=True).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Time'})

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What do you think is the problem? How to fix it.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think simpliest is use list comprehension with `transpose` by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) of `DataFrame` and last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

If need working later with `TimeSeries`, the best is also create `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x).T for x in l['cashflowStatementHistory']['FB']], sort=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```